# Creating multiple Entity Framework EDMX files for factory pattern use

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

People are doing clever things with Entity framework, but I think I'm doing something quite simple, and can't seem to get it going.

I have two separate databases. Database A and database B.

I need to create contexts to these databases separately, so I want a factory pattern that will instantiate either context for me. I am trying to use a database first approach.

I referenced Entity Framework via the Nuget package manager, and created a new item using Visual Studio. The only item with an EDMX extension to choose from was "ADO.NET Entity Data Model", so I've gone with that and selected database A.

The EDMX file has been generated, and I can see my entities. When it comes to accessing them programmatically, the entities have been dumped into the default namespace. This means that I get intellisense for the entity by going to my.namespace.datasource.TableA.

If I now create another EDMX file in the same area, the same entites will be dumped into the same place, and I'll get conflicts.

An example of the error I get is:

"The type 'my.namespace.datasource.Entities' already contains a definition for 'TableA'"

Why is this? Why isn't it creating a default namespace for that EDMX file that the entities will reside within? How can I have multiple EDMX files working in harmony and providing separate contexts when I need them?

Any help's appreciated!

Cheers,

Karl.

Answer (score 3):

- Option 1. Select model project item in solution explorer, go to item
  properties, set the property "Custom Tool Namespace" to the preferred
  value. Your generated code will be put in the namespace you've set.
- Option 2. Create two separate folders and put one model into the
  first folder, and one - into the second folder.
- Option 3. Put your models into separate projects.

**Note**.
If you're using VS2010 and any T4 generator (e.g., DbContext generator), you should:

- turn off default code generation by clearing "Custom tool" property for EDMX project items;
- set "Custom Tool Namespace" for T4 project items (e.g. `Model1.tt` and `Model1.Context.tt`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dennis! I did actually try options 1 and 2, and it didn't seem to affect the namespace of the generated POCs. Option 3 seems to be the best option so far!

Comment: @Karl: what generator are you using? Could you post custom tool name?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest. I installed EF5 via the NuGet Package manager, and I created the edmx file by add new -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

Comment: If you are using VS2012 the default code generation is DbContext and POCO entities. When resolving POCO entities EF ignores namespaces and then barfs if it find ambiguous match (the exception you got) - even separate folders/namespaces/assemblies won't help. Do these databases have the same schemas or they are different or only somewhat different? Do you want to share entity type definitions for both contexts? I think it will be hard to resolve this without answering the above quuestions first.

Comment: @Karl: as Pawel said, it will be better, if you'll tell us VS version you're using. VS2010SP1 + EF5 (installed via NuGet) + EF 5.x (project item template installed via Extension Manager) DbContext generator: options 1 and 2 works fine. I've added some notes to answer.

Comment: @Pawel: I'm using Visual Studio 2012. These databases do have the same schemas, although they are not likely to change very much, if at all.

I do want to share entity type definitions if possible, because I want to use a factory pattern to throw out either context.

Do you think that's do-able?

Thanks very much for your replies so far!

Comment: @Karl: "databases do have the same schemas" - so, why to create two different models?

Comment: @Dennis: If I'm not sure whether the models will change or not, is it better to program against the same model and just change the connection string? What would you suggest?

Comment: @Karl to me it looks like you will be much better off using Code First. So - remove both edmx files from your project - you won't need these. Create an assembly containing all your entities (you could try using "reverse engineer from database option" in EF Power Tools Beta 2 (note that there is a glitch with PowerTools if you have VSUpdate1 but there is an easy workaround) to avoid creating your entities manually. Note these will be POCO entities. Create two DbContext derived contexts and add DBSet properties for entity sets. You should be good to go.

Comment: If schemas are the same using one context type (2 different instances) as suggested by Dennis could be even better.

Comment: Thanks very much to you both! I went code-first with one model, and all seems to be working very well indeed. I'm switching contexts by specifying an enum to choose between the two data sources. Thanks again! What's the best way to finish this question? Should I mark the above answer as the answer, or answer my own question?

Comment: @Karl: I think, Pawel should post his comment about Code First as answer, and you should accept it.